# How can I efficiently extract a string delimited by braces in C#?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, delimiter

I'm writing software to parse a large file. This large file denotes new objects using opening, {, and closing, }, braces. Within these delimiters there are more delimiters of the same type & pattern.

What I need to be able to do (efficiently) is extract the contents of the outer brackets from the main string....

For example say I have a file containing the following data....

```
Jake James
87
{
    Henry James
    57
    {
        Lisa James
        18

        Luke James
        24
        {
            Bart James
            8
        }

        Dexter
        22
    }
}
```

I need a function that will extract everything inside of a set of delimiters, but on the same level... So if the above was put into a string called sample.. we could do this...

```
string extracted = ExtractStringBetweenDelimiters(sample, "{", "}");
```

Which would result in extracted holding the string

```
    Henry James
    57
    {
        Lisa James
        18

        Luke James
        24
        {
            Bart James
            8
        }

        Dexter
        22
    }
```

and sample holding the remaining string.

```
Jake James
87
```

My current function to do this is like this (it works, but it's slow).

```
  static public string ExtractStringBetweenDelimiters(
     ref string original,
     string opening_delimiter,
     string closing_delimiter)
  {
     int first_delimiter = original.IndexOf(opening_delimiter);
     if (first_delimiter >= 0)
     {
        int total_open = 1;
        int opening_index = first_delimiter + opening_delimiter.Length;

        for (int i = opening_index; i < original.Length; i++)
        {
           // Check if we have room for opening_delimiter...
           if (i + opening_delimiter.Length <= original.Length)
           {
              for (int j = 0; j < opening_delimiter.Length; j++)
              {
                 if (original[i + j] != opening_delimiter[j])
                 {
                    break;
                 }
                 else if (j == opening_delimiter.Length - 1)
                 {
                    total_open++;
                 }
              }
           }


           // Check if we have room for closing_delimiter...
           if (i + closing_delimiter.Length <= original.Length)
           {
              for (int j = 0; j < closing_delimiter.Length; j++)
              {
                 if (original[i + j] != closing_delimiter[j])
                 {
                    break;
                 }
                 else if (j == closing_delimiter.Length - 1)
                 {
                    total_open--;
                 }
              }
           }


           if (total_open == 0)
           {
              // Extract result, and return it...
              string needle = original.Substring(opening_index, i - opening_index);
              if (original.Length > i + closing_delimiter.Length)
              {
                 original = original.Remove(first_delimiter, i + closing_delimiter.Length);

                 if (original.Substring(0, 1) == "\n")
                 {
                    original = original.Remove(0, 1);
                 }
              }
              else
              {
                 original = "";
              }

              if (needle.Substring(0, 1) == "\n")
              {
                 needle = needle.Remove(0, 1);
              }

              if (needle.Length > 0 && needle.Substring(needle.Length-1, 1) == "\n")
              {
                 needle = needle.Remove(needle.Length - 1, 1);
              }

              return needle;
           }
        }
     }

     return "";
  }
```

Comment: This looks like your source data could be converted to XML, then you could use an XML parser. No point reinventing the wheel. Can you change your source format?

Comment: I wish, but no. It's part of a larger construct which I'm not able to change.

Comment: Could you pre-process it to convert to XML? It looks very convertable. Also is the tabulation guaranteed to be correct? That would be an extremely easy way to process it by counting the tab depth.

Comment: No, the tab indentation isn't always correct. I actually remove all tabs from the file before starting to process it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `String.Substring()`?

```
public static string[] ExtractStringBetweenDelimiters(string sample, string open, string close)
{
    int openIndex = sample.IndexOf(open);
    int closeIndex = sample.LastIndexOf(close);

    var top = sample.Substring(0, openIndex);
    var bottom = sample.Substring(openIndex + 1, closeIndex - openIndex - 1);

    return new [] { top, bottom };          
}
```

This gets the results from the top level of the string. To get the next level, pass the value at index 1 of the returned array to the function. If unbalanced delimiters are a concern perhaps you could count them beforehand to make sure there are an equal number of each.

Comment: This wouldn't work because the next entry (after Henry) would be thrown in as this is just getting the LAST closing delimiter... But the last closing delimiter isn't always the one that we want.

Comment: Os that due to bad data format? Can you give an example of the data where the last closing delimiter wouldn't be used?